# Difference Between To, For, and Till

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

The sentences below are describing how a certain event will happen on Friday, and I'm very excited.

> I can't wait to Friday comes.
>
> I can't wait for Friday comes.
>
> I can't wait till Friday.

Which one is correct and what is the difference between them?

Comment: You could say *I can't wait to see Friday come,* or *I can't wait for Friday to come.* Or *I can't wait [till, until, ’til](http://grammarist.com/usage/until-till-til/) Friday [comes]*. They're all pretty much equivalent - precise contexts might possibly make some more suitable than others, but then again they might not.

Comment: But sometimes people might misunderstand that you really can not wait till Friday. (need to do or finish something before Friday)

Comment: Well, only you know exactly what you mean. If a child says *I can't want till my birthday next week*, we'd normally understand that to mean the child is in a state of agitated anticipation. It's always *possible* he's actually demanding to be given his birthday present *now*, rather than having to wait until next week, but that's just the way people speak in all languages. The distinction between ***can't*** and ***really don't want to*** is often deliberately blurred to strengthen one's position.

Answer (score 3):

To is traveling, until, till, and til are time. If you check their definition, depending on use, they're not interchangeable. Like to and too.

Answer (score 1):

With due deference to FumbleFingers, the first sentence is fine if somewhat colloquial.

> A) The next appointment to see the dentist is this Friday afternoon.
>   B) I can't wait **to** Friday.  I need to see the dentist *today*!

I imagine the use of "to" here is a gradual phonetic shift from the more grammatically correct *till* which is itself synonymous with *until*.  It would be more "formal" to say:

> I can't wait **till/until** Friday.

Also, as FumbleFingers mentions, this use of "to" is not usually written except as a quote or as reported speech.  Otherwise your second sentence is incorrect, and should instead be:

> I can't wait **for** Friday (**to come**).

meaning that you are really looking forward to Friday.

Comment: When I first looked at this one, I simply ignored OP's initial *wait **to** Friday* as an effectively meaningless mistake, but I see now it's actually a perfectly credible misapprehension for *learners* - particularly if much of their exposure to English involves the spoken rather than written form. Unlike the related *I **should of** written this properly*, this particular error is rarely reflected in the written form, but when you consider how *Wait t'ya hear this!* is often enunciated, it's easy to see how "aurally-focused" learners could be misled.

Comment: ...having said that, I think it might be a good idea to explicitly point out in your answer text itself that *this use of **to** is rarely reflected in the written form*. Otherwise you might give the impression that writing it like that is on a par with things like ***wanna, gonna, hafta***. Which imho it's not - they reflect a "reduction" that's consciously recognised as an accurate and non-confusing eye-dialect representation of actual speech, whereas to native speakers OP's *written* ***to*** immediately signals *Syntax error! Non-native speaker alert!*